# Python 2 vs 3: consistent results with getting a byte from byte string

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

Is there any simple way to get consistent results in both Python 2 and Python 3 for operatioIn like "give me N-th byte in byte string"? Getting either byte-as-integer or byte-as-character will do for me, as long as that will be consistent.

I.e. given

```py
s = b"123"
```

Naïve approach yields:

```py
s[1] # => Python 2: '2', <type 'str'>
s[1] # => Python 3: 50, <class 'int'>
```

Wrapping that in `ord(...)` yields an error in Python 3:

```py
ord(s[1]) # => Python 2: 50, <type 'int'> 
ord(s[1]) # => Python 3: TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

I can think of a fairly complicated compat solution:

```py
ord(s[1]) if (type(s[1]) == type("str")) else s[1] # 50 in both Python 2 and 3
```

... but may be there's an easier way which I just don't notice?

Comment: Related [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: You *are* aware that support for 2.x is about to be officially dropped, yes?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes, and I'm totally aware of tons of our users potentially using Python 2, so unless there's something very dire, I'd like to keep our Python 2 support too.

Comment: Ouch, sorry to hear about that. I wish you the best of luck in avoiding people yelling at you about it in the future. Maintenance is never fun IMX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A length-1 slice will be also be a byte-sequence in either 2.x or 3.x:

```
s = b'123'
s[1:2] # 3.x: b'2'; 2.x: '2', which is the same thing but the repr() rules are different.
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the most elegant choice in my case — no bulky code and no extra libraries to require!

Answer (score 2):

If you use (converting if needed) the `bytearray` type, behavior will be identical on both versions, always matching Python 3 behavior of `bytes`. That's because `bytearray` is actually a distinct type on Python 2 (with Python 3 behavior), where `bytes` is just an alias for `str` there.

The more typical solution would be to use the `six` compatibility library, which provides [`six.indexbytes`](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.indexbytes), so on either version of Python, you could do:

```
>>> six.indexbytes(s, 1)
50
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    def index(s, n):
        return s[n]
elif sys.version_info.major == 2:
    def index(s, n):
        return ord(s[n])
else:
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Comment: For the record, this is *exactly* what [`six.indexbytes`](https://six.readthedocs.io/#six.indexbytes) does.

Comment: Definitely, `six` is a nice arrow in your quiver when writing Python 2/3 code.

Comment: Looks like a recipe for bugs if Python ever goes to v4.

Comment: @Holloway Fixed. But TBH I hardly think that it was relevant for the problem at hand.

Comment: The reason for my question is exactly to *avoid* rolling such a lengthy construct myself every time I need it. Using `six.indexbytes` or, better yet, length slice approach suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58411754/487064 is what I was looking for.